Compare the proportion of multiple diseases between 2 groups
I'm conducting an analysis on data derived from two groups subjected to different environmental conditions. Here's a brief overview:

Group A: 750 individuals exposed to smoke.
Group B: 1500 individuals exposed to clean air.
Both groups were recruited at two different timepoints, with half from each group at each timepoint.
Each individual in the study will develop one of three mutually exclusive diseases. My goal is to determine if there's a significant difference in the overall disease proportion between the two groups.

I initially considered performing a simple proportion test for each disease, comparing the prevalence in Group A versus Group B. However, this approach seems redundant since an increase in one disease's prevalence in a group inherently decreases the prevalence of others due to the mutual exclusivity.
Here's a snippet of the code I'm using:
# Load necessary library
library(dplyr)

# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Define the number of individuals in each group
n_group_a <- 750
n_group_b <- 1500

# Define the recruitment timepoints
timepoints_a <- c(rep(1, n_group_a / 2), rep(2, n_group_a / 2))
timepoints_b <- c(rep(1, n_group_b / 2), rep(2, n_group_b / 2))

# Define the diseases
diseases <- c("DiseaseX", "DiseaseY", "DiseaseZ")

prob_group_a <- c(0.7, 0.15, 0.15)  # Disease1 is more common in Group A
prob_group_b <- c(0.33, 0.33, 0.34)  # Equal probabilities in Group B

# Create data frame for Group A
group_a <- data.frame(
    id = 1:n_group_a,
    group = rep("A", n_group_a),
    exposure = rep("smoke", n_group_a),
    timepoint = timepoints_a,
    disease = sample(diseases, n_group_a, replace = TRUE, prob = prob_group_a)
)

# Create data frame for Group B
group_b <- data.frame(
    id = (n_group_a + 1):(n_group_a + n_group_b),
    group = rep("B", n_group_b),
    exposure = rep("clean_air", n_group_b),
    timepoint = timepoints_b,
    disease = sample(diseases, n_group_b, replace = TRUE, prob = prob_group_b)
)

# Combine the two groups into one data frame
combined_data <- bind_rows(group_a, group_b)

# Display the combined data
head(combined_data, 20) # Display the first 20 rows

# create a proportion DF
proportion_df <- combined_data %>%
    group_by(disease, exposure) %>%
    tally() %>%
    left_join(., combined_data %>%
        group_by(, exposure) %>%
        tally(n = "n_total")) %>%
    mutate(fraction = n / n_total)


# visualize result proportion
ggplot(proportion_df, aes(x=disease,y=fraction, fill=disease))+
    geom_col()+
    facet_wrap(~exposure, ncol=1) + 
    theme(legend.position = "none")+
    ylab("Fraction of disease")+
    geom_text(aes(label = round(fraction,2)), vjust = -0.5, position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5) +
    theme_minimal() %+%
    theme(legend.position = "none") + 
    ylim(0, max(proportion_df$fraction) * 1.15)  # Adjust y-axis limit for label space


# calculate differences per disease
pro_test_res <- lapply(unique(proportion_df$disease), function(disease) {
    n_success <- proportion_df %>%
        filter(disease == !!disease) %>%
        pull(n)
    n_total <- proportion_df %>%
        filter(disease == !!disease) %>%
        pull(n_total)
    res <- prop.test(x = n_success, n = n_total) %>%
        broom::tidy() %>%
        mutate(disease = disease)
}) %>%
    bind_rows() %>%
    select(-c(contains("conf"), "method", "parameter", "alternative"))

While the above methodology is straightforward, it feels like I'm missing a more streamlined approach that could capture the essence of the analysis with a single test.
Does anyone have suggestions or insights on a potentially more effective statistical method for this scenario?
Cheers!

How have you balanced confounders between the two groups?

I would fit some sort of cross-sectional multinomial model with exposure and time period as covariates (ideally with other variables as well to control for the confounders that Adam mentioned). This will take the dependence between the outcomes into account.
Here's a multinomial logit example using your data. It returns the average marginal "effects" of clean air for each disease (on the probability scale, along with the p-values and 95% CIs. The three effects sum to one, as you anticipated:
> summary_effects
disease = DiseaseX:
 contrast          estimate     SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 clean_air - smoke   -0.377 0.0207  6   -0.427   -0.326

disease = DiseaseY:
 contrast          estimate     SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 clean_air - smoke    0.189 0.0179  6    0.145    0.233

disease = DiseaseZ:
 contrast          estimate     SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 clean_air - smoke    0.188 0.0179  6    0.144    0.232

Results are averaged over the levels of: timepoint 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

Graphically, it looks like this:

You can see that disease X is less likely by 0.38 pp, whereas Y and Z increase by 0.19 pp. These changes match the differences of the bars in your graph; all of them are highly statistically distinguishable from zero.
You might want to add a joint test that all three AMEs are zero (or whatever makes sense for your research questions).

R Code:
# Install necessary packages (commented out)
# install.packages("dplyr")
# install.packages("nnet")
# install.packages("emmeans")
# install.packages("ggplot2")

# Load necessary libraries
library(dplyr)  # For data manipulation
library(nnet)  # For multinomial logit models
library(emmeans)  # For estimated marginal means and comparisons
library(ggplot2)  # For visualization

# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Define the number of individuals in each group
n_group_a <- 750
n_group_b <- 1500

# Define the recruitment timepoints for each group
timepoints_a <- c(rep(1, n_group_a / 2), rep(2, n_group_a / 2))
timepoints_b <- c(rep(1, n_group_b / 2), rep(2, n_group_b / 2))

# Define the diseases
diseases <- c("DiseaseX", "DiseaseY", "DiseaseZ")

# Define the probabilities of each disease for each group
prob_group_a <- c(0.7, 0.15, 0.15)  # DiseaseX is more common in Group A
prob_group_b <- c(0.33, 0.33, 0.34)  # Equal probabilities in Group B

# Create data frame for Group A
group_a <- data.frame(
  id = 1:n_group_a,
  group = rep("A", n_group_a),
  exposure = rep("smoke", n_group_a),  # Group A has 'smoke' exposure
  timepoint = timepoints_a,
  disease = sample(diseases, n_group_a, replace = TRUE, prob = prob_group_a)
)

# Create data frame for Group B
group_b <- data.frame(
  id = (n_group_a + 1):(n_group_a + n_group_b),
  group = rep("B", n_group_b),
  exposure = rep("clean_air", n_group_b),  # Group B has 'clean_air' exposure
  timepoint = timepoints_b,
  disease = sample(diseases, n_group_b, replace = TRUE, prob = prob_group_b)
)

# Combine the two groups into one data frame
combined_data <- bind_rows(group_a, group_b)

# Ensure categorical variables are factors
combined_data <- combined_data %>%
  mutate(
    group = factor(group),
    exposure = factor(exposure),
    timepoint = factor(timepoint),
    disease = factor(disease)
  )

# Fit the multinomial logit model with interaction between timepoint and exposure
model <- multinom(disease ~ timepoint  + exposure, data = combined_data)

# Summary of the model
summary(model)

# Calculate estimated marginal means (emmeans) for the fitted model
em <- emmeans(model, specs = ~exposure | disease)

# Display the estimated marginal means
print(em)


# Calculate pairwise comparisons with confidence intervals on the response scale
effects <- confint(pairs(em, reverse = FALSE)) # Calculate pairwise comparisons of the emmeans and obtain confidence intervals

# Display the pairwise comparisons with confidence intervals and p-values
summary_effects <- summary(effects, infer = c(TRUE, TRUE))  # infer = c(TRUE, TRUE) adds p-values

summary_effects

# Create the plot
ggplot(effects_df, aes(x = contrast, y = estimate, color = disease)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower.CL, ymax = upper.CL), width = 0.2) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "red") +  # Add horizontal line at y = 0
  facet_wrap(~ disease, scales = "fixed") +
  labs(
    title = "Estimated Average Marginal Effects",
    x = "Contrast",
    y = "Percentage Points"
  ) +
  theme_minimal()


When performing an epidemiologic analysis of prevalence from panel data - i.e. data where individuals are measured at several longitudinal timepoints, the number of cases considered in analyses are a mix of prevalent and incident disease, as well as a mix of age-period-and-cohort (APC) effects. All of these need to be considered to refine your essential question "to determine if there's a significant difference in the overall disease proportion between the two groups.".
At a minimum, I would approach this problem from the perspective of fitting a generalized estimating equation to these data with fixed effects for participant age at study entry, sex, calendar year of assessment, and exposure-type. The inference for the coefficient for exposure type would provide some preliminary inference on a possible association between smoke-exposure and disease status.
From an epidemiologic perspective, I believe models for each disease individually are probably the most useful. But in terms of morbidity, you can fit a model for the continuous endpoint of number of diseases, to infer the average number of diseases differing between exposure accounting for calendar year, sex, and age.

The concern you have may not be one at all. After all, in the classic 2x2 contingency tables, every time you have more "outcomes" in a column, you will have less "no outcome" in that column. That is equally true for many/most nxm contingency tables; the results are conditional on the margin totals. And the Fisher-exact test (or $\chi^2$ test if none of the proportions are "too close to 0 or 1) will handle this very well (in fact, this is exactly how the Fisgher test works). In your case, you have a 3x2 contingency matrix (3 diseases, 2 groups), and I would use a Fisher-exact test, which will tell you "if there's a significant difference in the overall disease proportion between the two groups".

Thank you very much for your comment, that makes sense! For the 3x2 contingency matrix, I would ignore the fact that individuals from the group are sampled at 2 different timepoints. Do you think this would make a difference and how would I include the timepoint information?

How to handle the different timepoints depends on whether the length of exposure, and the time after exposure are the same for both time points or not. If they are the same, then you can combine the 2 timepoints w/o any issue (most clinical/biological studies do not start their subjects exactly on the same day simply for practical reasons). As long as subjects at timepoint 2 were exposed to smoke for the same amount of time, and the disease state was observed at the same time after exposure, then all is fine. Otherwise, these become 2 new IV's, and contingency table will not work.
